# GetComputedStyle node not working - Is not defined

Tags: css, node.js

I'm writing a webscraping script and I'd like to use `getComputedStyle()` however it doesn't work on node. I get errors saying `getComputedStyle is not defined`

If I try `global.getComputedStyle`, it says global.getComputedStyle is not a function

Obviously window doesn't exist on node so I can't use that.

What do I need to use?

```
function sortElementsByFontSize(elements: any[]): any[]{
    return elements.sort((a, b) => {
        let aFontSize = parseInt(global.getComputedStyle(a)['fontSize']);
        let bFontSize = parseInt(global.getComputedStyle(b)['fontSize']);
        console.log("Comparing: " + aFontSize + " - " + bFontSize);
        if(aFontSize === bFontSize){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return aFontSize > bFontSize ? 1 : -1
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`getComputedStyle()` is something that exists in a browser, not in nodejs.

If this wasn't clear to you, nodejs is a Javascript environment and it supports the latest standards for the Javascript language, but it has its own runtime library that supports things like networking and file I/O.  Similarly, the browser supports the latest standards for the Javascript language, but has its own runtime library that supports things like `getComputedStyle()`.

Nodejs doesn't do any HTML rendering on its own, doesn't parse or understand CSS, etc...

So, to use a function like `getComputedStyle()` you have to either run your Javascript in a browser environment or use a library within nodejs that gives you access to an actual browser engine such as [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) which uses the Chromium browser engine to create a browser-environment where you can run some Javascript.

Comment: I understand that. I'm already running Puppeteer to emulate a browser. The problem is that neither `getBoundingClientRect` or `getComputedStyle` are working. The first one returns 0s for all of its values and the second one just simply doesn't exist, that's despite this tutorial telling you that you can use both of these without issue: https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-scrape-prices-from-any-ecommerce-website/.

Comment: I've even tried doing `page.evaluate(element => window.getComputedStyle(element) with puppeteer but that is erroring saying the object is not of type element when I'm giving it HTMLDivElements

Comment: @jm123456 - If you want someone to try to help you with your puppeteer code, you'd have to show that code and the context around it in your question.  We can't help with code we can't see.  Puppeteer, used properly, can execute code like this.